# Trying to Convert my Model to IEnumerable<Model>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable

In my `MedicalProductController` I am trying to convert a `MedicalProduct` (model class) named "product" into `IEnumerable<MedicalProduct>` so it can be passed to `GetMedicalProductViewModelList`, which will return an `IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel>` (viewModel class).

I am trying to keep SQL calls to a minimum. as per advice of other stackoverflow members.

But "product" fails to turn into `IEnumerable<MedicalProduct>` in my `MedicalProductController` Class

### MedicalProductController

```
public class MedicalProductController : Controller
{
    private MvcMedicalStoreDb _db = new MvcMedicalStoreDb();

    // other CRUD code omitted for brevity.

    // =============
    // Edit HttpGet
    // =============

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        MedicalProduct product = _db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var productList = product as IEnumerable<MedicalProduct>;
        var viewModelList = GetMedicalProductViewModelList(productList);
        return View(viewModelList);
    }

    // =============
    // Edit HttpPost
    // =============

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(MedicalProduct product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var productList = product as IEnumerable<MedicalProduct>;
        var viewModel = GetMedicalProductViewModelList(productList);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // =====================
    // Mapper Class Helper
    // =====================

    public IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> GetMedicalProductViewModelList(IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> productList)
    {
        var brandList = _db.Brands.ToArray();

        var mapper = new MedicalProductMapper();

        return mapper.MapMedicalProductViewModel(productList, brandList);            
    }
```

And just in case it is helpful, here is the mapping class:

## MedicalProductMapper

```
public class MedicalProductMapper
{

    // =====================
    // Model to ViewModel
    // =====================

    public IEnumerable<MedicalProductViewModel> MapMedicalProductViewModel(IEnumerable<MedicalProduct> medicalProductList, IEnumerable<Brand> brandList)
    {
        var brandSelectListItem = brandList.Select(b => new SelectListItem()
                                                {
                                                    Text = b.Name,
                                                    Value = b.Name
                                                });

        var viewModelList = medicalProductList.Select(p => new MedicalProductViewModel() 
                                {
                                    BrandID = p.BrandID,
                                    BrandName = brandList.SingleOrDefault(b => b.ID == p.BrandID).Name,
                                    BrandSelectListItem = brandSelectListItem,
                                    ID = p.ID,
                                    Price = p.Price,
                                    Name = p.Name
                                });



        return viewModelList;
    }

    // =====================
    // ViewModel to Model
    // =====================

    public MedicalProduct MapMedicalProduct(MedicalProductViewModel VM)
    {
        var model = new MedicalProduct()
        {
            Name = VM.Name,
            Price = VM.Price,
            BrandID = VM.BrandID
        };

        return model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of

```
var productList = product as IEnumerable<MedicalProduct>;
```

Try

```
var productList = new List<MedicalProduct> { product };
```

You can't cast to `IEnumerable<MedicalProduct>` if it's not an `IEnumerable`, what I did in this example is first create a new List of type `MedicalProduct` and then add the product to the List.

List is one of the types that implement IEnumerable